# Spring DataSize class not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to run an appliaction using spring framework, but an exception is always raised :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToDataSizeConverter.getConvertibleTypes(StringToDataSizeConverter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.add(GenericConversionService.java:507)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.addApplicationConverters(ApplicationConversionService.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.configure(ApplicationConversionService.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance(ApplicationConversionService.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:472)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at fr.edf.as.meteo.MeteoedfApp.main(MeteoedfApp.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

There are 2 modules : commons and editic, both of them has a pom.xml file :

**commons 'pom :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>meteoedf</artifactId>
        <groupId>fr.edf.as.meteo</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.edf.as.meteo</groupId>
            <artifactId>editic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-violations</artifactId>
            <version>0.24.0-RC.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.24.0-RC.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.26.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**editic's pom : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.edf.as.meteo</groupId>
        <artifactId>meteoedf</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.edf.as.meteo</groupId>
    <artifactId>editic</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**And the main pom : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.edf.as.meteo</groupId>
    <artifactId>meteoedf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>editic</module>
        <module>commons</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Meteoedf</name>

    <repositories>
    <!-- more information at https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
            <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-mafr.edf.as.meteo.editic.repositorytory -->
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-plufr.edf.as.meteo.editic.repositorytory -->
    </pluginRepositories>

    <!-- jhipster-needle-distribution-management -->

    <properties>
        <!-- Build properties -->
        <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
        <node.version>v10.15.0</node.version>
        <npm.version>6.4.1</npm.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m</argLine>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
        <profile.no-liquibase />
        <profile.swagger />
        <profile.tls />

        <!-- Dependency versions -->
        <jhipster-dependencies.version>2.1.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
        <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
        <hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- The javassist version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/${hibernate.version} -->
        <javassist.version>3.22.0-GA</javassist.version>
        <!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
        <liquibase.version>3.5.5</liquibase.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</mapstruct.version>

        <!-- Sonar properties -->
        <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9001</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.exclusions>commons/src/main/webapp/content/**/*.*, commons/src/main/webapp/i18n/*.js, commons/target/www/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>S3437,S4684,UndocumentedApi,BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarcloud.io/coding_rules?open=Web%3ABoldAndItalicTagsCheck&rule_key=Web%3ABoldAndItalicTagsCheck is ignored. Even if we agree that using the "i" tag is an awful practice, this is what is recommended by http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>src/main/webapp/app/**/*.*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>Web:BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarcloud.io/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS3437&rule_key=squid%3AS3437 is ignored, as a JPA-managed field cannot be transient -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>squid:S3437</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarcloud.io/coding_rules?open=squid%3AUndocumentedApi&rule_key=squid%3AUndocumentedApi is ignored, as we want to follow "clean code" guidelines and classes, methods and arguments names should be self-explanatory -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>squid:UndocumentedApi</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarcloud.io/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS4684&rule_key=squid%3AS4684 -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S4684.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S4684.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S4684.ruleKey>squid:S4684</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S4684.ruleKey>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths>${project.testresult.directory}/lcov.info</sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths>
        <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <sonar.tests>${project.basedir}/src/test/</sonar.tests>

        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-property -->
    </properties>

</project>
```

I searched on the Internet but it seems like this error isn't common, and might be linked with dependencies' version ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is mismatching Spring Boot (2.1.8.RELEASE) and Spring Core (5.0.12) versions. Core is 5.0.12, because it is transitive dependency of spring-beans 5.0.12.

[DataSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html) is part Spring Core since 5.1. Boot version 2.1.x expects Core 5.1, as one can see from release notes. Exact version one can found from [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.pom).

One can of course define versions manually, but that is lot of works - especially when Spring Boot version changes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Because it is rather tedious (though doable) to match versions manually, one should use spring-boot-dependencies in depencyManagement ([link to documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And remove version from dependencies such as spring-beans and spring-context etc.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Version should be defined (instead of inheriting from spring-boot-dependencies) only if there is valid reason to use some other version.